# Rela Relocation ELF64 Does it points to Operation or Operand?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, 64-bit, elf

I still writing my ELF64 Loader in Java and in a REL(A) Section description one stated that the offset of an entry points to the operation and not the actual value to manipulate.

But inspecting my example for the 10 Type (S+A) for a System V I visiting exactly that it is pointing to the operand for a B9 move (ecx i think).

Also I wonder since I wanted a 64 bit C program it shows only a 32 bit address. What do I miss?

Comment: It points to the value of course. The relocation doesn't know or care about the opcode which may not be a single byte. Relative addresses use 32 bit offsets in 64 bit mode too.

Comment: An opcode that *reads from* or *writes to* your program memory does not need changing, but its immediate value does -- because that is the enitre point of relocating a program in its actual place in memory.

Comment: OK, I was afraid I have to write something like a disassembler for certain operations. Makes more sense this way so in the end the documentation was wrong in that sentence. I will send a correction node to the author. Thanks.